# Nodejs and MongoDB : Unable to return value from a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var config = require('config.json');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db(config.connectionString, { native_parser: true });

module.exports.getNextSequence =  function (name) {
    var temp;
    db.collection("counters").findAndModify(
        { _id: name },           // query
        [],                      // represents a sort order if multiple matches
        { $inc: { seq: 1 } },    // update statement
        { new: true },           // options - new to return the modified document
        function (err, doc) {
            temp = doc.value.seq;
            console.log(temp);   // <-- here the temp is getting printed correctly
        }
    );
    return temp; 
}
```

Using the above code, I am not able to return the value of `doc.value.seq`. When doing `console.log(obj.getNextSequence)` it prints `undefined`.

I want the function to return the value of `doc.value.seq`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with mongoskin so I'm not positive this is correct, but a database query is typically asynchronous, so you need to access the queried value via a callback.

I'm guessing your "getNextSequence" function is returning the "temp" variable before the database query completes (i.e. before the "temp = doc.value.seq" statement).

Try something like this:

```
module.exports.getNextSequence =  function (name, callback) {
    var temp;
    db.collection("counters").findAndModify(
        { _id: name },           // query
        [],                      // represents a sort order if multiple matches
        { $inc: { seq: 1 } },    // update statement
        { new: true },           // options - new to return the modified document
        function (err, doc) {
            temp = doc.value.seq;
            callback(temp);
        }
    );
}
```

Then access "temp" from within the callback passed to getNextSequence.

Answer (score 1):

`findAndModify` is an *asynchronous* function. Your `console.log` line will run **after** you return `temp`, which will therefore be `undefined`. In order to get this to work, you'll want to use an asynchronous approach of your own. There are two available approaches in your situation.

[Callbacks](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm):

You're already using a callback, which you provide as the final argument to `findAndModify`. You could extend this approach and feed this into a callback of your own, as follows:

```
module.exports.getNextSequence =  function (name, callback) {
    db.collection("counters").findAndModify(
        { _id: name },
        [],
        { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        { new: true },
        function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            callback(null, doc.value.seq);
        }
    );
}
```

Of course, this will require you to pass a callback into `getNextSequence` and follow the callback pattern upstream. You might also want to handle the error from `mongoskin` and do some handling of your own.

[Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises):

If you don't provide a callback to `findAndModify`, it will return a promise, which you can chain on to, as follows:

```
module.exports.getNextSequence =  function (name) {
    return db.collection("counters").findAndModify(
        { _id: name },
        [],
        { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
        { new: true }
    ).then(function (doc) {
        return doc.value.seq;
    });
}
```

Again, this will require you to follow the promise pattern upstream. You'll want to read up on promises if you choose this approach, so that you can correctly handle errors, which I have not addressed in the example above.